# SharePoint development deployment problems

Tags: development

I am getting the following error, when trying to deploy the visual studio generated Blank SharePoint Project.

> Error 1   Error occurred in deployment step 'Retract Solution': Cannot
>   connect to the SharePoint site: `http://srv-sharepoint:35018/`. Make
>   sure that this is a valid URL and the SharePoint site is running on
>   the local computer. If you moved this project to a new computer or if
>   the URL of the SharePoint site has changed since you created the
>   project, update the Site URL property of the project.

I set up a new application so have these 3 now: (Name, URL, Port)

> SharePoint - 80     `http://srv-sharepoint/`    80
>
> SharePoint Central Administration v4     `http://srv-sharepoint:32152/`    32152
>
> SharePoint - Test     `http://srv-sharepoint:35018/`    35018

Its all on the server. And my project URL is `http://srv-sharepoint:35018/`

When I changed it to the admin port, it "ran" but just loaded up the admin panel.

What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: If this is your first time to 'deploy' to a new site, you may get this because Visual Studio has different 'recipes' for what happens when you choose to deploy. On a brand spanking new site, there is no pre-existing solution to retract, so, a retraction step will fail (but perhaps the remaining steps of the deployment will succeed?). Then, on the second attempt to deploy, the retraction will succeed b/c there is now something there to retract.

Comment: Of course, the specific language in your error does not support my previous comment so much.

Comment: After you created your web app, did you proceed to create an actual sharepoint site at that location?
(will post script in a new answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need to create an actual site in your new web application:

```
stsadm -o createsite -url http://srv-sharepoint:35018/ -owneremail yourname@contoso.com -ownerlogin CONTOSO\myname -siteTemplate "STS#1" -description "This custom site is a Visual Studio test bed. It may get blasted away and recreated without notice." -title "My Development"
```

Comment: Yea, I created a template of a site, via the sharepoint interface (recently). But have hit an error, where I cant open the sharepoint generated one, due to permissions.. Despite Im accessing it from the server. So this could be the answer for my question, but haven't been able to confirm. +1. I'll get back to you

Answer (score 1):

Are you having Administrator privileges on your system? If not...

1. Add yourself as the administrator
2. Add yourself to SharePoint Farm Admin Group
3. Make sure that you have DB Owner access to SharePoint Content DB

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is an [Alternate Access Mappings](http://www.mssharepointtips.com/tip.asp?id=1102&page=2) problem. Can you browse your site using `http://srv-sharepoint:35018/` or `http://localhost:35018/` ? Try replacing `srv-sharepoint` with `localhost` and see if it works.

Comment: THanks, but it does not work. The only site I can browse, with `srv-sharepoint` or `localhost` is the administration v4.

Comment: Can you browse your site using this URL: http://srv-sharepoint:35018/? and if you change the project URL in visual studio to http://localhost:35018/ you get the same error?

Comment: I cannot browse that no. And yes, Its still the same error :(

Answer (score 0):

Before deployment make sure you have admin access on your system. Add your self in Farm admin group. Add check your permission on Content DB on site.